# Map object values to keys - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I have an array from an API call.

```
var response = {
  "data": {
    "data": [{
      "1": "Arun",
      "index": "name"
    }, {
      "1": 70.78,
      "index": "score"
    }]
  }
}
```

I connect to a lot of other API's and they return me a similar response but the keys change. Sometimes it might be

```
var response = {
  "data": {
    "data": [{
      "values": "Harry",
      "index": "name"
    }, {
      "values": 45,
      "index": "score"
    }]
  }
}

var response = {
  "data": {
    "data": [{
      "4": "Richard",
      "index": "name"
    }, {
      "4": 98,
      "index": "score"
    }]
  }
}
```

I would like to get an array like this.

```
[
  {
    name: 'Arun',
    score: 70.78
  }
]
```

This is what I did.

```js
var response = {
  "data": {
    "data": [{
      "1": "Arun",
      "index": "name"
    }, {
      "1": 70.78,
      "index": "score"
    }]
  }
}

const result = [];

const mappedData = _.map(response.data.data, (item) => {
  return {
    [item.index]: item[1]
  };
});

const resultObject = _.reduce(mappedData, (result, currentObject) => {
  for (const key in currentObject) {
    if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      result[key] = currentObject[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
}, {});

result.push(resultObject)


console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

So instead of hardcoding "1" or "values" in the map function, is there a more universal way to get the key and achieve the same result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reduce` rather than `map`, so you're updating the same object, not creating an array.

And since the property containing the value can vary, I use a loop to look for the first property that isn't named `index`, and use its value.

```js
var response = {
  "data": {
    "data": [{
      "1": "Arun",
      "index": "name"
    }, {
      "1": 70.78,
      "index": "score"
    }]
  }
}

const mappedData = response.data.data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  var value;
  // find the property that isn't named "item"
  for (var i in item) {
    if (i != "index") {
      value = item[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  acc[item.index] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(mappedData)
```

There's no need for lodash for this, the built-in `reduce` function is fine (but `_.reduce` will work similarly).

Comment: Thanks Barmar. So in the reduce, I do not want to use item[1]. Is there a more universal way?

Comment: You need to eliminate the need for `acc[item.index] = item[1]` as the number `[1]` will change on different requests.

Comment: If that can vary, how is the code supposed to know what the property is?

Comment: Something based on key?

Comment: It seems very strange that an API would return data like this. Are you sure there's no way to find out what the key is without searching?

Comment: I need to talk to 5 different teams to change their API's. I wonder they would do that as they might need to change their code as well.

Comment: There was a missing '}', added that and it returns undefined now.

Comment: @Barmar my concern is  what if key changes to something else instead of `index `. I have modified your solution in my answer.

Comment: Then I think you're screwed. You need some way to tell which property is the name and which is the value.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only care about the values of that object **and** it only has two keys you can do this quite easily in lodash with [**reduce**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#reduce) & [**fromPairs**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#fromPairs):

```js
var response = { "data": { "data": [{ "1": "Arun", "index": "name" }, { "1": 70.78, "index": "score" }] } }

const rv = (o) => _.reverse(_.values(o))
const r = _.reduce(response.data.data, (a,c) => _.fromPairs([rv(a), rv(c)]))

console.log(r)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The same thing converted to ES6 would be:

```js
var response = { "data": { "data": [{ "1": "Arun", "index": "name" }, { "1": 70.78, "index": "score" }] } }

const rv = (o) => Object.values(o).reverse()  // reverse values
const fp = (arr) => arr.reduce((r, [k,v]) => (r[k] = v, r), {}) // from pairs
const result = response.data.data.reduce((a,c) => fp([rv(a), rv(c)]))

console.log(result)
```

The main idea here is to first get the object values in an array form, reverse them so the `key` & `value` are in the correct order and then `reduce` that array via `from pairs` to create the final object.

The main advantage of this approach is that we never deal with the object keys and only focus on the values which is what you really care about. This way the keys can be any value and it would still not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting the key-pair `index` and using the first `value` of the resulting object:

```
const mappedData = _.map(response.data.data, (item) => {
  var tempObj = Object.assign({}, item)
  var index = tempObj.index;
  delete tempObj.index;
  var otherData = Object.values(tempObj)[0];
  return {
    [index]: otherData
  };
});
```

Comment: Use a copy of the `item` so you don't delete the original and prevent latter debugging problems. If you are not going to use the response latter, then you can use `item` instead of `tempObj`.

Comment: I wouldnt be using the original response again at all. The code you provided works but the array has 2 objects, whereas I need an array with one object and two keys in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just modified the @barmar approach. I have used `Object.keys` to get keys from object. This will remove the any hard-coded  dependency.

```js
var response = {
  "data": {
    "data": [{
      "1": "Arun",
      "index": "name"
    }, {
      "1": 70.78,
      "index": "score"
    }]
  }
}

const mappedData = response.data.data.reduce((acc, item,i) => {
  
  var key = Object.keys(item);
  acc[item[key[1]]] =  item[key[0]]
  return acc ;
      
}, {});

console.log(mappedData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The order of properties in objects is not guaranteed. You can't be sure that the value will always be `key[0]` rather than `key[1]`.

Comment: But if you're willing to take that risk, you can use `Object.values` instead of `Object.keys`. Then you can do `acc[values[1]] = values[0]`;

Comment: @Barmar I will look into your suggestion. As what i See in OP response, Object.key approach seems fine to me.

Comment: Most implementations currently preserve order, but it could change at any time and the code will stop working.